# python pdb breakpoints cleared after reloading

Tags: python, breakpoints, pdb

Consider the following program:

```
def foo(x):
     return x * 2
def bar(y):
     return y - 2

# more definitions here

def main():
     foo(21)
     bar(44)
     # ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I might load this into `pdb`:

```
$ python -m pdb main.py
(Pdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at /path/to/main.py:102
(Pdb) run
```

However, when I make changes to the file somewhere above `def main():`, save it, and reload it with `(Pdb) run` to restart the program, the breakpoints get all messed up because the line numbers have changed. So I have to reset all the breakpoints every time I reload the program.

This gets very tedious when I have multiple breakpoints set on different functions.

Is there any way to have pdb break on a function and have it automatically update the breakpoint's line number when the program is reloaded?

Thanks

Comment: If possible, use a more advanced debugger such as the one in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple pdb.set_trace() inside your code. They will break the code while you run it. the first one launches pdb.